# how to fix issue file_exists function in php always return false

Tags: php, file, file-exists

I am using PHP and I am trying to rename a file using `file_exists()` function, but the code always execute else case, although the file already exists.
Here is my code:

```php
if(file_exists('../media/imgs/books/'.$_POST['old_name'])){
    rename('../media/imgs/books/'.$_POST['old_name'],'../media/imgs/books/'.$_POST['book_name']);
}
else {
    echo "file not found";
}
```

When I execute this code, it always returns false and shows me "*file not found*".
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Have you tried an absolute path to make sure you are checking the right directory?

Comment: First: are you inserting the file name in the form manually or by a uploading a new file?. Second if you input the name manually do you consider the extension of the file.

Comment: Try to `var_dump($_POST['old_name'])`. This will show you what is being evaluated. I suspect that your filename has spaces or special characters in it, which PHP needs to deal with. Take a look at `htmlspecialchars` in the php manual if that's the case.